# XmlDataDocument - Improper restriction of XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a project scanner complaining with a Warning about

```
XmlDataDocument serializedContent = new XmlDataDocument();
```

and

```
serializedContent.Load(objStream);
```

and giving this recommendation to use:

> The best way to prevent XXE attacks is to disable XML entity
> resolution by disabling inline DD setting DtdProcessing to
> DtdProcessing.Prohibit or by disabling XML Entity resolution setting
> the XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver property to null:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings () ;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing. Prohibit;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
```

Here's the code that I have:

```
[Serializable]
...

XmlTextWriter objSerializer = new XmlSerializer(...);
MemoryStream objStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter objwriter = null;

XmlDataDocument objSerializedContent = new XmlDataDocument();    // it complains here

objWriter = new XmlTextWriter (objStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

...

objSerializedContent.Load(objStream);    // it complains here
```

How can I apply that scan recommendation using reader if I'm using XmlTextWriter & XmlDataDocument?

Comment: Always add full error messages.

Comment: And specify _why_ XmlDataDocument and not XmlDocument.

Comment: I really don't get any error on the scanner beyond the text I added on the question now @HenkHolterman it's not really an error but a warning

Comment: Ok: always add full error and warning messages. Preferrably with error/warning number and stacktrace when available.

Comment: I did above in the question, that's the only thing I got, the scanner doesn't say much. @HenkHolterman

Comment: Well, there is an overload of the `Load` method that takes an `XmlReader` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_Xml_XmlReader_) thus if you use an `XmlReader` set up over your `MemoryStream` with the suggested `XmlReaderSettings` you might be able to avoid that warning, if it concerns you. But the snippets suggests the content of the MemoryStream is created by an `XmlSerializer` , I doubt that Microsoft API injects any DTD in the XML it output and therefore your `Load` call doesn't seem to able to run into XXE

Comment: I just want to silence the warning, I believe the serialization is correct. How can I implement `XmlReader` you mentioned? @MartinHonnen

Comment: See whether the code in the answer helps, haven't tested but I think it is better to post code in an answer than in a comment.

Comment: It's useful to be clear whether you want to make your application more secure, or whether you want to get rid of the irritating warnings from the scanner. These aren't always the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings () ;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing. Prohibit;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
```

and

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(objStream, settings)) {
  objSerializedContent.Load(xr);
}
```

instead of `objSerializedContent.Load(objStream)` your code uses an XmlReader over the MemoryStream where the XmlReader has the settings you want or need.

Comment: Do I need to enclouse everything inside the `using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(objStream, settings)) {` or just when loading the file?

Comment: @Albert, to use the XmlReader in a clean way the code I posted suffices. On the other hand any `Stream` also implements `IDisposable` so I would recommend to wrap your use of the MemoryStream in another `using (MemoryStream objStream = new MemoryStream()) { ... }`. But that is really an issue that has nothing to do with the original question.